# How to handle Facebook graph response to mysql table

Tags: facebook, graph, phpmyadmin

I am using facebook graph to post to a page and when successful, this returns an id. How do I get this id and place it into a mysql column/cell? I'm kind of new to Facebook graph api.

Comment: What is a phpmyadmin column? You mean a table/column in mysql? You have to write a script in any language...

Comment: Yeah mysql, I only just realised it. I understand I require a script to complete the request. Although I'm seeking assistance as to how to do it php. I have searched online, and can't find how to handle the response from posting to a page. The response being the post id.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody can give you a "short" introduction to PHP, MySQL and the Graph API in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I'm not after a introduction, just want to know how how someone would handle the id response from Facebook (code).

Comment: You get it back as response to your API call. If you don’t know what the data structure looks like, then use `var_dump` to find out.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than I thought.

Just

```
$id = $response['id'];
```

I could then use $id to submit it to the database.